# How would I create a class for user that doesn't have to login?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm creating a class diagram for an assignment, and for the system I'm creating the assignment for, the client is able to check the status of his job with a job no. without actually logging in. How would I represent this client in a class diagram?

This is my attempt:

[image]

and the according UC:

[image]

Comment: Where's the diagram?

Comment: What is the purpose of the class diagram? To design the structure of the source code, to design the structure of the database, to model the real world, to model the application functionality, something else?

Comment: @bigbounty This is [what](https://i.imgur.com/LDnmeQZ.png) I have for now. This is the [use case](https://i.imgur.com/8lNWx8B.png) to show the system i'm trying to model.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl To describe the structure of the system

Comment: Your UC is just wrong. `Login` is no use case!

Comment: @ThomasKilian Wait really? I made it based on the example my school gave me. Here is what's in my subject guide. [example](https://i.imgur.com/srglo8A.png)

Comment: First of all, what do you want to say by the UC diagram? From the modelling perspective, it's wrong. Use only primary use cases (the reasons why the user uses the software such as Update Job Status) as a start. Secondly, if anyone is able to see something without login in, there is no need to make it in a conceptual model. I could be e.g. precondition from a use case or there will be no step "logging in" in a scenario of that use case.

Comment: Yeah, that's plain wrong. I posted quite a number of answer where I explained why login is no UC (since it does not deliver value). It's a simple constraint to be applied. Sooo many people carry that along and keep spreading that login-UC nonsense :-/ I always recommend to read Bittner/Spence about UCs.

Comment: Why does `Sparepart` have add and remove operations? That does not seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your question: In your class diagram, you wonder how to model a client who is able to use the application without actually logging in. In the comments, you have clarified that the class diagram is intended to describe the structure of the system.

Most likely, a client who does not log in, is not explicitly represented as a structure element in the software. Therefore, this client should not be shown in the class diagram at all.